# Django foreignkey get_or_create

Tags: django, foreign-keys

Trying to check and see if a artist exists, if not add or link to foreignkey and save.

Here are the models

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    """Artist model"""
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)


class Track(models.Model):
    """Track model"""
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

Here is the script that checks

```
artist_id, created = Track.objects.get_or_create(artist_id=artist.title)
try:
    artist_title = artist_id.artist_set.all()
except IndexError:
    artist_slug = slugify(artist_title)
    try:
        artist = Artist.objects.create(title=artist_title, slug=artist_slug)
        # artist.add(artist_id)
        artist.save()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Comment: cool - but do you have the complete trace. Line number and such? I've just tried to run the code and I get error for the first line of the script that checks. What is `..._or_create(artist_id='...')`?. Track does not have a field called `artist_id`

Comment: Aah! `artist_id, created = Track.objects.get_or_create(artist_id=artist.title)` should be `artist_id, created = Track.objects.get_or_create(artist__id=artist.title)` then your error is produced...

Comment: You're using it wrong - I'll post an example in a sec

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For this example, accessing the get_or_create will not work when referencing a foreign key.
This example makes it work:

```
a = Artist.objects.create(title='Sinch', slug='sinch')
t = Track.objects.create(artist=a, title='bitmap', slug='bitmap')
Track.objects.get_or_create(artist__id=1)
(<Track: Track object>, False) #is returned.
```

If you are trying to collect a track via the id of artist. To work around this - do:

```
try:
    a = Artist.objects.get(id=2)
except DoesNotExist:
    artist_title = 'title'
    artist_slug = slugify(artist_title)
    artist = Artist.objects.create(title=artist_title, slug=artist_slug)
    artist.save()

t, c = Track.objects.get_or_create(artist=a)
```

---

I know this is probably not what your looking for - But if you tell me the workflow you wish to apply, I can post more applicable code.

Answer (score 2):

Do it as following.

```
artist_id, created = Track.objects.get_or_create(artist=Artist(title=artist.title))
```

This is the reference.
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13915